# update eclipse view from another process

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, eclipse-plugin, listener

My eclipse plugin extends `ViewPart` and implements `IConsoleLineTracker`. I have created a `Text` view within `createPartControl(Composite parent)` and have obtained the view within `lineAppended(IRegion region)` using `page.findView(ViewID)` . Within `lineAppended()`, getter methods on the view works fine. However setter methods on the view throws null pointer exception.

What should I do?

```
public class SampleView  extends ViewPart implements IConsoleLineTracker {
public static Text viewer=null;

public static final String ID = "views.SampleView";

IConsole console;
@Override
public void dispose() {
}

@Override
public void init(IConsole console) {
    this.console=console;
}

public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    viewer = new Text(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    viewer.setText("hi");        
}

@Override
public void lineAppended(IRegion region) {
       try {
        String line = console.getDocument().get(region.getOffset(), region.getLength());

        IViewPart part=getPage().findView(".views.SampleView");

        if (part instanceof SampleView) {
          viewer = ((SampleView) part).viewer ;
          viewer.getDocument();    //works fine when I write the content to file
          viewer.setText("hi hi"); //throws NullPointerException
        }

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
public void setFocus() {
    viewer.setFocus();
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the stack trace